# Getting a cors error from stripe redirect because of my redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm getting the following error for my stripe redirect:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource 
at http://localhost:5000/api/stripe/create-checkout-session. (Reason: CORS request did not 
succeed). Status code: (null).
```

And I've tried everything I can think of. However I think that it's due to my array data being stored in localStorage in my redux. Would anyone happen to know how to fix it?

Redux:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

//stores products in local storage
const items = localStorage.getItem('products') !== null ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products')) : [];

//Empty cart to start
const initialState = {
  products: items,
  totalQuantity: 0,
  totalAmount: 0,
};

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  //State grabbed from above
  initialState,
 
  reducers: {

    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      //grabs item id from array and assigns it to payload
      const item = state.products.find(item => item.id === action.payload.id);

      if (item) {
        //increments payload quantity
        item.quantity += action.payload.quantity
        //total quantity assigned to payload
        state.totalQuantity += action.payload.quantity;
        //total price
        state.totalAmount += (action.payload.price  * action.payload.quantity);
      }
      else {
        //pushes items to reducer array
        state.products.push({
          id: action.payload.id,
          title: action.payload.title,
          img: action.payload.img,
          price: action.payload.price,
          count: action.payload.count,
        });
        //Grabs items from local storage
        localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(state.products));
        //increments quantity
        state.totalQuantity += action.payload.quantity;
        //total price
        state.totalAmount += ((action.payload.price) * action.payload.quantity);
      }
    },

    removeItem: (state, action) => {
      //Grabs index of item from data array
      const itemIndex = state.products.findIndex(item => item.id === action.payload);
      if (itemIndex !== -1) {
        const item = state.products[itemIndex];
        //decrements item quantity
        state.totalQuantity -= item.quantity;
        //decrements price 
        state.totalAmount -= item.price * item.quantity;
        //Removes item from array
        state.products.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        //Grabs item from local storage
        localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(state.products));
      }
      //No items in cart
      if (state.products.length === 0) {
        state.totalQuantity = 0;
        state.totalAmount = 0;
      }
  },
    updateCount: (state, action) => {
      //Finds item ID in array
        const item = state.products.find(item => item.id === action.payload.id);
        if (item) {
          //changes quantity
          const countDiff = action.payload.count - item.count;
          //Assigns item  count to payload
          item.count = action.payload.count;
          //Total item quantity in payload
          state.totalQuantity += countDiff;
          //Total price 
          state.totalAmount += item.price * countDiff;
        }
      },
  },
})


// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { addToCart, removeItem, resetCart, updateCount} = cartSlice.actions

export default cartSlice.reducer
```

Stripe prop:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const url = "http://localhost:5000/api";

const PayButton = ({cartItems}) => {
    console.log(cartItems)
    const handleCheckout = () => {
    axios.post(`${url}/stripe/create-checkout-session`, {
        cartItems,
        //put user _id from backend get request here
    }).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.url) {
            window.location.href = res.data.url;
        }
    }).catch ((error) => {
        console.log(error.message)
    })
    }

  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={() => handleCheckout()}>Check Out</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default PayButton
```

Stripe route:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);
require('dotenv').config();

const router = express.Router();

//grabs cart from cart items component

router.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const cartItems = req.body.cartItems;
  const lineItems = cartItems.map((item) => {
    return {
      price_data: {
        currency: 'usd',
        product_data: {
          name: item.title,
          images: [item.img],
        },
        unit_amount: parseFloat(item.price) * 100,
      },
      quantity: item.count,
    };
  });


  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    billing_address_collection: 'required',
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA'],
    },
    line_items: lineItems,
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${process.env.WEB_APP_URL}/checkout-success`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.WEB_APP_URL}/cart`,
  });

  res.send({url: session.url});
});


module.exports = router;
```

I tried changing the cors in my server, removing localStroage from my slice, posting from my frontend,and I'm expecting it to redirect to stripe onClick.

Comment: What makes you say this is related to your use of redux? What host are you using for your dev server? Are they the same origin?

Comment: My frontend is on 3000, and my server is on 5000, and I think that it's a redux issue because the Stripe API could be blocking the posts from the fronend because the data isn't secure enough, but that's the part I can't figure out, so perhaps it's something else that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",` in `package.json` file so that your frontend app is able to communicate with your backend.